# Registry setting for virtual wifi max number of connections / clients?

Tags: windows, wifi, virtual, connection

I'm building an app that has functionality that creates on the fly a new virtual wifi utilizing the Windows 7 / 2008 features.  I can create it just fine, but am looking how to limit the maximum number of connections.  By running a "netsh wlan show hostednetwork" command to view my settings - it shows (by default 100), but it HAS to be somewhere in the registry right? - I can't see any settings available for this either at the command line or using the api - so I have to assume it's stored in the reg. 
I see vwifi and hostednetwork registry keys in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\ - Wlansvc\parameters\hostednetworksettings, etc... but can't find any reference to add a "MaxClients" value (or similar) - would like to limit it to only one connection.
Has anyone seen any references to this, or know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using something like the following code.

```
WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS hostedNetworkConnSettings;
hostedNetworkConnSettings.hostedNetworkSSID = ssid;
// set the number of clients that may connect to your hosted network
hostedNetworkConnSettings.dwMaxNumberOfPeers = nPeers;

// set the new connection setttings
WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty(
                  m_WlanHandle,
                  wlan_hosted_network_opcode_connection_settings,
                  sizeof(WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS),
                  (PVOID)&m_HostedNetworkConnSettings,
                  NULL,
                  NULL
              );
```